# Java Send form data in post request

Tags: java, java-8, multipartform-data

I am trying to send this key and value pair as a form data in my java request but i'm facing issues while sending this key and value pair directly

i have tried this so far

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8081/path' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic dfghjkljhgfdsdfghjklhgfcdx7654' \
--form 'key="value"'
```

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = this.builder.build();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(env.getProperty("pod-url"));
request.addHeader("Authorization", env.getProperty("pod-auth"));
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `https://some/local.com` is *supposed* to be, but that's not like any URL I ever saw.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the way like this:

```
var httpPost = new HttpPost(env.getProperty("pod-url"));

var postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value"));

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters, "UTF-8"));
```